# I want Build Real time Data passing Client to Server without Without using WEBSOCKETS IN JAVA

Tags: java, angularjs, websocket, client-server

I want Build Real-time Data passing Client to Server without **Without using WebSockets** IN JAVA, How I can build that service **without using external libraries** 
I am using Java for Back-end and Angularjs for Frontend in addition maven using dependency management
If you have Sample source code project please share

Comment: You can use long polling: https://javascript.info/long-polling

Comment: help me if anyone know more details

Comment: anyone know more